# Connect local repo on multiple PCs to a single remote repo on bit-bucket(git)

Tags: git, bitbucket, repo

Probably this is simpler than I think but here is the problem: Recently we moved to git from perforce and were successfully able to move our latest files. Now here is the catch, there are multiple PCs that were being used that already have the folder/files that are on the remote. How do I connect all these local repos to the remote one without having to clone or remove the existing local repos?

Also, one thing to keep in mind is that people might be making changes in their local repos already, so I don't want them to lose their progress. Is there a way to easily work through this?

Comment: Do you mean `git remote add origin` ?

Comment: That will just add the origin right? Will it also recognize that the files on the remote are same as the files on local repo? I don't want to commit and push the same files unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what version control tools are precisely made for, the exact issue you are talking about(If I understand your query correctly anyways.) For starters, you are going to want to come up with a process to get all of the individual work done from separate users and get that merged into the official master branch. Start with the most important features and who has to most critical features built. Do this one by one until everyone is working on the same master branch. After you get this sorted out, you will want to come up with a process or a system to become more organized so this doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact commands or process for this? As I added in the comment above  I don't want to commit and push the same files unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, I can try but depending on exactly what you have going on you may run into issues with conflicting code but here is the general idea.                                           PC1- $git fetch origin                                                                                                      $git checkout -b merged_branch                                                                                 $git merge first_computer_branch         (now commit the changes ) $git commit -m "Merge changes from first computer"    (repeat ssame process for PC-2)